# CRM with Azure: Time zone Sync issue (An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party)

Tags: azure, sdk, timezone, crm

I have an API project created in AP.Net MVC and hosted in Azure. This portal is using a CRM environment as back end. When we connect our portal to our azure server environment (from a location in same time zone, but some hours difference because of DST), we get the below error:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. 
>   Innerexception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: At least one security token in the message could not be validated.

Any help?